# Extract index of first unique element in large array in Swift

Tags: performance, strings, programming-challenge, swift, set

I'm using the following code to return [the first index of a unique character](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/?tab=Description) in a large `String`. It works fine until I get to large strings, where it times out.

Is there a faster way to accomplish the goal of getting a hold of the unique character's index using `NSCountedSet`?

**Update**

The string contains 25,000 characters. I refactored the original post to extract the unique chars, then cycle through the array and see if each index is contained within the `uniqueChar` array. It's a little faster, but not fast enough to pass Leetcode's timer.

```
func firstUniqChar(_ s: String) -> Int {
    guard Set(s.characters).count > 0 && s.characters.count > 0 else { return -1 }
    let stringArray = s.characters.map({String($0)})

    let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: stringArray)

    var uniqueChars: [String] = []

    for char in countedSet {
        if countedSet.count(for: char) == 1 {
            uniqueChars.append(String(describing: char))
        }
    }

    for index in 0..<stringArray.count {
        if uniqueChars.contains(stringArray[index]) {
            return index
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Comment: Please define "large" and "times out".

Comment: large = 20,000 characters. By timing out, I mean the site I'm trying to submit it to says it's too pokey and won't return the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial test

```
guard Set(s.characters).count > 0 && s.characters.count > 0 else { return -1 }
```

is not needed, the remaining code already handles the case of an
empty string.

Determining the unique characters from `countedSet` can simpler be done
with a filter operation instead of a for-loop:

```
let uniqueChars = countedSet.filter { 
    countedSet.count(for: $0) == 1
} as! [String]
```

But actually that list is not needed at all because all you have to do
in the final loop is to find the first character which has a count
of one. The function then looks like this:

```
func firstUniqChar(_ s: String) -> Int {
    let stringArray = s.characters.map({String($0)})
    let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: stringArray)
    for index in 0..<stringArray.count {
        if countedSet.count(for: stringArray[index]) == 1 {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

which is simpler and a bit faster than the original one.

This can further be improved by avoiding the conversion of each
character to a string and the array, and operating on the UTF-16
view of the given string directly:

```
func firstUniqChar(_ s: String) -> Int {
    let countedSet = NSCountedSet()
    for char in s.utf16 {
        countedSet.add(char)
    }
    for (index, char) in s.utf16.enumerated() {
        if countedSet.count(for: char) == 1 {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

`NSCountedSet` is from the Foundation library and works with
`NSObject` instances. The previous method works because the
`UInt16` value is automatically wrapped into an object when
added to the counted set. This conversion can be avoided by
using a native Swift dictionary instead, which makes the
code *much* faster:

```
func firstUniqChar(_ s: String) -> Int {
    // Map from character to number of occurrences:
    var counts: [UInt16: Int] = [:]

    for char in s.utf16 {
        if let cnt = counts[char] {
            counts[char] = cnt + 1
        } else {
            counts[char] = 1
        }
    }
    for (index, char) in s.utf16.enumerated() {
        if counts[char]! == 1 {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

---

*Benchmarks.* Test code:

```
let s = String(repeating: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy", count: 1000) + "z" + String(repeating: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy", count: 1000)
print(s.characters.count) // 50001

let start = Date()
let i = firstUniqChar(s)
let end = Date()

print(i, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
```

Results (on a 3.5 GHz Intel Core i5 iMac, compiled in Release
configuration):

```
Your original function:  0.084 sec
First improvement:       0.058 sec
Second improvement:      0.014 sec
Last function:           0.003 sec
```

---

The last method can be more compactly written as

```
func firstUniqChar(_ s: String) -> Int {
    // Map from character to number of occurrences:
    var counts: [UInt16: Int] = [:]

    for char in s.utf16 {
        counts[char] = (counts[char] ?? 0) + 1
    }

    let index = s.utf16.enumerated()
        .first(where: { counts[$0.element]! == 1 })?
        .offset
    return index ?? -1
}
```

without changing the performance.

Comment: Thank you! I never realized how slow `NSCountedSet` is versus a native Swift dictionary until I saw this.